# When does the NullPointerException occur?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

```
class  CardBoard    
{  
    Short  story = 200;  
    CardBoard  go(CardBoard cb)
    {
        cb = null;  
        return cb;  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args)   
    {  
        CardBoard  c1 = new  CardBoard();  
        CardBoard  c2 = new  CardBoard();  
        CardBoard  c3 = c1.go(c2);   
        //  expecting  null  pointer  exception      
        c1  =  null;  
        // do stuff;  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why would there be a NPE here ?

Comment: You'll only get a NPE when you actually try to call a method on c3 - not just for assigning null to it.

Comment: is there any more code?

Comment: @dystroy Sorry i am very new to java please could you tell me when does it usually occur??

Comment: I don't want to be rude but if you look for a general answer on when a NPE usually occurs then it's not the right site. Try Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no NPE in the commented line, because `c1` and `c2` are not null. In addition, in the `go` method the `cb` variable is set to `null`,  but that doesn't affect the actual object!

```
CardBoard  c1 = new  CardBoard();  
CardBoard  c2 = new  CardBoard();  
CardBoard  c3 = c1.go(c2);
```

The situation after these lines is:

```
c1 != null
c2 != null
c3 == null
```

So why should you get an NPE?

You have to understand what references are! Passing an object to a method as you do in the call `go(c2)` and in the method setting the parameter to `null` does *not* affect the original object instance!

It's like:

```
object c1 = new object();
object c2 = c1;

c1 = null
```

results in

```
c1 == null
c2 != null // !!!
```

Answer (score 3):

i don't understand why are you expecting NullPointerException.
Basically you are just trying to say:
**CardBoard  c3 = null;**

If you want NPE, you can do:
**CardBoard  c3 = null;**
**c3.go(c2);**
Here, c3 is null, so this will throw a NPE since you are trying to do:
null.go(...);

Comment: you are welcome Karthik :)

Answer (score 1):

> When is the null pointer exception occur?

Whenever you are invoking an instance method or accessing an instance field on a reference variable that refers (points) to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Now, try :

```
public static void main(String[] args)   
{  
    CardBoard  c1 = new  CardBoard();  
    CardBoard  c2 = new  CardBoard();  
    CardBoard  c3 = c1.go(c2);   
    //  expecting  null  pointer  exception      
    c1  =  null;  
    c3.go(c2);
}
```

and see what happens… ;)
You will get your NPE sure enough.

(You have to actually use your null pointer to get your exception)

Answer (score 1):

NullPointerException will only occur if you try to access any methods or varibles with a reference pointing to nothing i.e. null.

I have made changes in your code to get NullPointerException :

```
class CardBoard {
Short story = 200;

CardBoard go(CardBoard cb) {
    cb = null;
    return cb;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CardBoard c1 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c2 = new CardBoard();
    CardBoard c3 = c1.go(c2);
    // expecting null pointer exception
    c1 = null;

    // If you try to call a method or access any member variable with null reference you will get the exception
    c3.story = 20; //NullPointerException will occur

    // do stuff;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

e.g.

```
Class Apple
{
 void applePrint()
 {
  System.out.println("Apple");
 }
}

Class Mango
{
 void mangoPrint()
 {
  System.out.println("Mango");
 }
}
```

Suppose somewhere in your code, you do

`Apple a;`

`Mango m;`

If you try to use this variable `a` or `m` to access Class members,

```
a.printApple(); or m.printMango();
```

It will throw NPE

i.e. you define the reference variables to the classes' objects but don't actually create them

`Apple a = new Apple();`
`Mango m = new Mango();`

[Have done it a lot when i was new to Java]

Comment: @KarthikRk Welcome!. On a side note, read `HeadFirst Java`  it is helpful to clear simple concepts

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)   
{  
    CardBoard  c1 = new  CardBoard();  
    CardBoard  c2 = new  CardBoard();  
    CardBoard  c3 = c1.go(c2);   // go method is returning 'null' so c3=null
    //  expecting  null  pointer  exception      
    c1  =  null;  
    c3.go(c2);  // you will get NullPointerException here.
}
```

when you invoke `go()` method on `c3` then you will get `NullPointerException`

You will get `NullPointerException` when you invoke method for those **reference variable** which are assigned to `null`.